# Multi platform app development vs operating system development

Tags: android, ios, windows-mobile, multiplatform

I want to know how do you develop a multi platform app and/or for one operating system. E.g. If I want to develop an app for all operating systems (IOS and android and windows mobile) is that going to be a mobile site rather than a app or can I develop one app for all platforms.

I know duh... If I want to develop for android I just develop for android. And
The same goes for IOS.

Is there any articles I can read or that you know of that can help me find out.

E.g. The Facebook app did they design one for every platform and now they have to maintain all? Or do they only have one?

Any good articles/tutorials/books that can read or watch to show me more.

Comment: From my experience, it's quicker and cheaper to make an app that can be deployed across all platforms, these apps (in most cases) are of the poorest quality. On the flip side, an app that is individually designed for each platform is very expensive but it also produces the best quality apps. This only applies for apps though, games are a bit different.

Comment: Will a cross platform be more web based or can you write one cross platform.  I agree with you about the quality of apps if they are designed for each platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to develop separate app for every platform.
If you want to develop single app that run on every app you can use any framework.
If you are familiar with C# you can use [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com). 
Another option is [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com). With phonegap you write HTML and JS.

Comment: I agree, that's for the links, I also agree with Steven above, I think is better quality to write apps for every platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can design apps for cross-platform compilation, ie FreeRDP is one example. It is available for Android, iOS, MAC OSX, Windows.

For the above you need to put a wrapper or interfaces between your app functions and the OS specific functions.